Why is sigma calculation from R lm inconsistent with my understanding of RSE of no intercept model?
I am trying to understand the lm fitting process in R. what I understand is the sigma is residual standard error (standard deviation with number of parameters degrees of freedom). So if I have no intercept, it should be equal to sd function. So, I run:
ctl <- c(4.17,5.58,5.18,6.11,4.50,4.61,5.17,4.53,5.33,5.14)
trt <- c(4.81,4.17,4.41,3.59,5.87,3.83,6.03,4.89,4.32,4.69)
group <- gl(2, 10, 20, labels = c("Ctl","Trt"))
weight <- c(ctl, trt)
lm.D90 <- lm(weight ~ group - 1) # omitting intercept
summary(lm.D90)$sigma == sd(lm.D90$residuals)
# FALSE

However, it doesn't give the same answer.

There's still two parameters being fit, so it matches $\sqrt{\frac{\sum r^2}{n-2}}$.

@PBulls but what are they? slope is one, what is the other one? Also I have 8 data points, R summary says 7 degrees of freedom.

Your example as shown has 20 data points (18 df); removing the intercept automatically adds another parameter for what would have been the reference level in your factor. Check your coefficients.

I found out my problem. As @PBulls denoted, this is categorical outcome, hence if there in no intercept, each factor will have it's own slope instead, hence df = n-2.
